# Unable to load class CompilationUnitEditor

Tags: eclipse

I was using eclipse indigo on opensuse 11.4 and also i use BIRT Report SDK for reporting, since after i updated my OS to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with eclipse Mars i was not able to open any birt report, it open file only in XML format. Then i installed one plugin http://download.eclipse.org/birt/update-site/4.4 (suggested by friend) and able to work on BIRT Report, but right after i installed that specified plugin i am not able to open any java file it gives me below error :

```
Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.
```

Even after uninstalling plugin which i installed for Birt SDK report it doesnt work, i tried searching on google and deleted `VariablesAndConstants.dat` from **workspace/./metdata...** folder but still it doesn't help.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Mars isn't a finished release. Try it again with Luna SR2.

Comment: Eclipse Mars is still in development and other components may not work with it yet. Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 is the latest full release.

Comment: Try launching Eclipse with the -clean option.